# How to access an object in another method in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object

I am trying to access a Player's score and update it when a user answers a correct question? However, when I reference the instantiated object I get an out of scope error.

I try to increment the user score within TriviaItem if they get the question correct.

Here is my repl.it link: https://repl.it/@tylermorales1/TriviaGame#Game.cs

```cs
// Game.cs
using static System.Console;
using System;

namespace Trivia
{
  class Game
    {
      public Game()
      {
        Setup();
        Play();
        GameOver();
      }

      public void Setup()
      {
        // get player name 
        Player user = new Player();
        user.score = 0;
      }

      public void Play()
      {
          // check answer
          playerInput = ReadLine();
          WriteLine(question.checkAnswer(playerInput));
        }
      }
      
      public void GameOver(){
        // Show total score
        WriteLine($"Your score is: ");
      }
    }
}
```

```cs
using static System.Console;

class TriviaItem
{
  public string Question;
  public string Answer;

  //overloaded constructor
  public TriviaItem(string question, string answer)
  {
    Question = question;
    Answer = answer;
  }

  // check answer
  public string checkAnswer(string userInput)
  {
    if(this.Answer.ToLower() == userInput.ToLower()) {
      user.score++;
      return "Correct!!!";
    } else {
      return $"\nIncorrect :(\n The correct answer is: '{this.Answer}'\n Your answer was: '{userInput}'";
    }
  }     
}
```

```cs
namespace Trivia
{
    class Player
    {
        public string name = "Anonymous Person";
        public int score = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another design problem is TriviaItem shouldn't be dealing with the user at all. `checkAnswer` simply return boolean, and it's up to `Game` class to increase the score based on the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `class Game` create a `private Player user` variable and instantiate inside your `Setup()` function.

Example how it would look:

```csharp
class Game{
    private Player user;

    public void Setup(){
        user = new Player();
    }
}
```

then you have access to `user.score` inside the whole Game class